# Seed for hash-table non cryptographic hash functions

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashset, hashcode

If one sets the hash table seed during resize or table creation to a random number, will that prevent the DDoS attacks on such hash table or, knowing the hash algorithm, the attacker will still easily get around the seed? What if the algorithm uses the Pearson hash function with randomly generated tables, unknown to the attacker? Does such table hash still need a seed or it is safe enough?

Context: I want to use an on-disk hash table for a key-value database for my toy web server, where the keys may depend on the user input.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by hash table "seed". In general hash tables don't have seeds, though some specific hash functions do have something they call a seed. In any event, the rest of the hash function is also critical to determining if it is adequately resistant to hash flooding attacks.

Comment: Usually most hash functions have seeds, just like random number generators. In fact, you can turn any hash function into a random number generator. And random number generator can be turned into a hash function too, if you seed with the value to be hashed. By hash-table seed I meant the seed value picked on init or during resize. I.e. one can try several seeds picking the one which gives less collisions, in case attacker probes the table.

Comment: siphash was specifically designed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is exist several approaches to protect your hash-subsystem from "adverse selection" attack, most popular of them is named [Universal Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing), where hash-function or it's property randomly selected, at initialization.

In my own approach, I am using same hash function, where each char adding to result with non-linear mixing, dependends of random array of `uint32_t[256]`. Array is created during system initialization, and in my code, it happening at each start, by reading the `/dev/urandom`. See my implementation in open source [emerSSL](https://github.com/emercoin/emcssh/blob/master/source/htable.c) program. You're welcome for borrow this entire hash-table implementation, or hash-function only.

Currently, my hash-function from the referred source computes two independent hashes for [double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) search algorithm.

There is "reduced" hash-function form the source, to demonstrate idea of non-linear mixing with S-block array"

```
uint32_t S_block[0x100]; // Substitute block, random contains

#define NLF(h, c) (S_block[(unsigned char)(c + h)] ^ c)
#define ROL(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32 - (n))))

int32_t hash(const char *key) {
  uint32_t h = 0x1F351F35; // Barker code * 2
  char c;
  for(int i = 0; c = key[i]; i++) {
    h  = ROL(h, 5);
    h += NLF(h, c);
  } 
  return h;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of using Barker? Isn't it just for signal transmission error detection?

Comment: Has any analysis been done where someone tried to find a hash flooding attack against this?

Comment: About Barker;s code: this code has minimal self-correlation vs cyclic shift. Since hash-function uses the cyclic shift, I need to produce maximal spreading value for input keys. As you see, barker code will return back to self-mapping after 65 iterations (5x13), this is more than enough, anyway, after 65 itteration there will be lot of values from S-block added.

Comment: About `hash flooding attack`. I think, you assume `muticollision`, correct? I developed this hash function for highly resist this attack. As you see, it uses cryptographic S-block, which value from which is using for non-linear mix next char into hash value. Thus, to select efficient multicollision, need to know value of S-block. This is 2K of random bytes (in my code, read from /dev/urandom), so this impossible to guess this. If you disagree - please try to create pair of collided keys, publish here, and thereafter we will run the hash (whits get 2K from /dev/urandom), and we'll see result.

Comment: Well, I compare this to siphash and the design criteria used by siphash. siphash uses a very conservative assumption: that the attacker can observe hash outputs for any inputs he chooses. siphash seems to survive under this assumption but your hash does not as it is relatively easy to recover the entire S-block table with not many more than 256 hashes. However, I'm a little skeptical about the validity of that model. I would like to see an explanation for why allowing the attacker to observe hash outputs of his choosing is reasonable.

Comment: I agree, my function does not assume situation, when attacker watching input and output. This is not cryptographically strict hash function, it keeps reasonable balance between performance and security for search purposes. For situation, as you assumed, a great approach to use any cryptographic hash function with a secret `salt`, for example - `sha1` or `sha3`.